# Crash in libjpeg.so when BitmapFactory.decodeStream called with inSampleSize

Tags: arm64, libjpeg

Since we need to support 64bit CPU in order to publish on Google Play.Then we found a strange crash happened in libjpeg.so in some devices(arm64-v8a).

Some logs are below:

`1 #00 pc 0000000000004a00 /system/lib64/libjpeg.so [arm64-v8a]
2 #01 pc 00000000000189d4 /system/lib64/libjpeg.so [arm64-v8a]
3 #02 pc 000000000001fef4 /system/lib64/libjpeg.so [arm64-v8a]
4 #03 pc 0000000000017188 /system/lib64/libjpeg.so (jpeg_read_scanlines+152) [arm64-v8a]
5 #04 pc 00000000002484e4 /system/lib64/libskia.so (SkJPEGImageDecoder::onDecode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+4532) [arm64-v8a]
6 #05 pc 000000000023d9b4 /system/lib64/libskia.so (SkImageDecoder::decode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkColorType, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+152) [arm64-v8a]
7 #06 pc 00000000000c7b48 /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeInputEventSender::NativeInputEventSender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, android::sp<android::InputChannel> const&, android::sp<android::MessageQueue> const&)+136) [arm64-v8a]
8 #07 pc 00000000000c857c /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeInputEventSender::receiveFinishedSignals(_JNIEnv*)+48) [arm64-v8a]
9 #08 pc 0000000000f647b8 /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (oatdata+16136120) [arm64-v8a]
10 java:
11 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:677)
12 android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:653)
13 com.c.a.utils.be.a(Encore:820)`

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.